# Kubernetes Service Account Token for GitLab Runner

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-runner

I'm trying to get the right token into the gitlab-runner-token without creating new services.

Can be done?
The token that is there is the wrong one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Obtain a token:

1. For a shared runner, have an administrator go to the GitLab Admin Area and click Overview > Runners
2. For a group runner, go to Settings > CI/CD and expand the Runners section
3. For a project-specific runner, go to Settings > CI/CD and expand the Runners section.

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/) for more information.